# Git - avoid committing conflicts?

Tags: git, macos, merge-conflict-resolution

is there a way (preferably for iTerm2 on MacOS) to disallow committing/pushing if there are still unresolved conflicts? Sending unresolved conflicts is forbidden in most GUIs but not in command line.

I have many developers who use CLI and sometimes they push unresolved conflicts, folks using git in editors don't have this problem because the editor won't allow this to happen.

Thanks for any insight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a bit of hair-splitting, but git *does* require all conflicts to be resolved before you can complete the commit.  However, from git's point of view, "resolved" means "the user has issued a `git add` command for the path that contained the conflict".  If the user says "this is resolved" while leaving the conflict markers in, git doesn't presume to know better.

And editors sitting on top of git are fundamentally no different.  They might present the conflict in a different way, or control the resolution workflow in a way that the user would have to jump through hoops to deliberately leave  conflict markers in the finished content.  But if a user literally says that the resolved content is

```
>>>>>>> their version
some change
-------
different change
<<<<<<< our version
```

no general-purpose tool can overrule that.

My advice is, if a user is committing conflict markers when they shouldn't be (and of course, almost always they shouldn't be), it's probably a training issue.  I would encourage them to either learn more about git conflict resolution, or use some of these tools that your other devs use, that you feel better protect them from these mistakes.  I think a user gets the most out of git if they take the time to learn it well enough to use the command line, but if they're not going to, then adding a "safety" around one of the numerous errors that can creep into under-informed usage of the command line tools... is a less than comprehensive solution.

If you nevertheless want to add such a safety, your best bet is to use git hooks.  You could add a pre-receive hook to the origin repo, so that it will reject any push containing commits containing files containing conflict markers.  You could also make this available for individual repos to use as a pre-commit filter, so they can catch the error early rather than wait until they're trying to commit to realize they have a bad history.

Just be aware that such a hook makes assumptions about the allowable content.  Those assumptions aren't outrageous if the script is well-written; for many types of content, there really *isn't* a good reason to commit conflict markers.  But as one (slightly silly) example, if someone had a need to commit a .txt file that descried a conflicted state, would your script be able to tell the difference and let that through?

Whether the potential edge cases are worth it for that extra layer of safety is something only you can answer for your project.  Again, my advice is to instead address why your users are making these mistakes in the first place.